Predicting the probability distribution of a deterministic dataset
In classical machine learning regression, we often assume the target variable $y$, given an input $x$, follows a probability distribution, allowing us to model and predict not just the expected value of $y$ but also its variance.
However, consider a scenario where the relationship between the input $x$ and the target variable $y$ is deterministic. That is, for any given input $x$, there exists a unique and theoretically knowable ground-truth $y$. We train a regression model to predict $y$ given $x$, generating a prediction $\hat{y}$. After predicting the value of $y$, we also want to predict the "uncertainty" or in some sense the "variance" of the prediction itself. We do this by predicting a value $\sigma$ for a given input $x$ (with prediction $\hat{y}$ and ground-truth $y$) such that the likelihood $f(y | \hat{y}, \sigma)$, where $f$ is the probability density function of a normal distribution centered at $\hat{y}$ with variance $\sigma^2$, is maximized. Intuitively, the $\sigma$ that we predict for a given $x$ tells us the uncertainty of the prediction in some sense.
Since there is no inherent randomness in the data generation process and the dataset is deterministic, the traditional probabilistic interpretation of variance does not directly apply. Therefore, the core question is:
Can we provide a probabilistic or formal interpretation for the predicted value $\sigma$ in this deterministic setting?  What does $\sigma$ represent if not the standard deviation of a conditional probability distribution $p(y|x)$?

Not an answer. But perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my Bayesian tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

Isn't this just a zero-variance Dirac distribution?

To be honest, I somewhat fail to see the problem.
Until we arrive at quantum levels, pretty much everything has a "theoretically knowable ground truth". If you know the position and current kinetics of your coin 0.01 seconds before it lands, you can likely predict whether it will land heads or tails.
The key thing is that we don't know.
The probabilistic interpretation does not necessarily come from "randomness ex nihilo". Where would such "irreducible randomness" come from, except from quantum phenomena? Even chaos theory does not tell you the end state is unknowable - it merely says that the end state depends highly nonlinearly on the start state, so the end state is again "theoretically knowable", you merely need to know the start state to an extremely high degree of precision. Again: the problem is that we simply don't have this precision of knowledge.
Therefore, probabilistics also come in as a heading under which we can include everything we don't know at a particular point in time. And your probability distribution (there are more such distributions than the normal!) simply encodes how our lack of knowledge about the start state and about the precise relationship between the start and the end states translates into uncertainty about the outcome.

I think you’re misunderstanding my question. In this problem, the start state is known with sufficient precision for the target to be determinable (e.g., by a human), but a machine learning model cannot predict the target perfectly due to its limitations. We aim to predict the "uncertainty" by estimating a $\sigma$ for each $x$, where the true target $y$ has its maximum probability density under a normal distribution centered at $\hat{y}$ with std $\sigma$. This $\sigma^2$ is not $Var[y|X=x]$ because $y$ is deterministic given $x$. So what is the probabilistic interpretation of $\sigma$?

In other words the "uncertainty" that I try to predict here if you look closely is not the uncertainty induced by the deterministic (or very small variance if you wish) target $y$ in the dataset. But in some sense it captures the distance between the prediction and and actual target, but it is not a "residual" because it doesn't have a orientation.

I would see that as just another facet of what I am describing. I wrote in terms of imperfect information and/or imperfect understanding of the relationship between inputs and outcomes. You describe an imperfect model. It again boils down to a kind of epistemic imperfection. ...

... $\sigma$ can be driven by two effects: if your model is generative in the sense of giving different outputs for equal inputs, then $\sigma$ is driven partly by this, and your RNG. In addition, $\sigma$ is driven by the imperfection of your model, and the distribution of inputs. The latter is crucial, because your predictions from your imperfect model will be more or less wrong depending on what inputs you feed it: $\sigma$ will be smaller if you feed in inputs on which the model performs well.

In this case the dependence is simply a function $$y=f(x).$$ We can give it a formally probabilistic form by writing
$$p(y|x) = \delta\left(y-f(x)\right).$$
The error in inferring the function may be treated probabilistically - e.g., because it is due to the inherently random initialization of the algorithm or other causes that we don't have control over. Any ML algorithm or simply numerical computation implies an error, at least due to the finite-digit representation of numbers in a computer (round-off error). This accumulates throughout computation in ways difficult to predict, and can be treated as random. In this case the delta function in the last equation can be seen as broadened by error, e.g.,
$$
p(y|x) =\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{\left(y-f(x)\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$
